# C casting return values of structures

Tags: c, function, struct, casting, kernighan-and-ritchie

On an old C compiler that only passes structures by pointers I fortunately have a structure that is 4 bytes long.  Which is the size of a long (not int) on this system.

The code I'm porting (awk V7 or 32V) has many functions that return this structure by value.

I'm trying to find a way to cast the structure a long and visa versa and while I have managed this for variables the cast fails with the return value of a function.  I would be forced to use a temp long and then cast that.  This means more than a simple define to solve my issue and means avoidable recoding.

Is there a way I can do this with just defines?

I have some sample code here that I'm playing around with. Sample code from different system has long of 64 bits so using int32 as long.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _obj { char a; char b; short c; } Obj;

#define OBJ2INT *(int32*)&
#define INT2OBJ *(Obj*)&

/* Obj */ int32 newObj(a, b, c) /* was returing Obj */
char a; char b; int c;
{
    Obj newobj;
    newobj.a = a;
    newobj.b = b;
    newobj.c = c;
    return OBJ2INT newobj;
}

int main(argc, argv)
int argc; char *argv[];
{
    Obj a, b;
    int32 t;

    t = newObj('a', '1', 1));
    a = INT2OBJ t; /* this works but require recoding with a temp variable */
    b = INT2OBJ newObj('b', '2', 2); /* this is not allowed. even though the value is on the stack there is no address for return value */

    printf("a = %c %c %d\n", a.a, a.b, a.c);
    printf("b = %c %c %d\n", b.a, b.b, b.c);
}
```

Comment: Your `OBJ2INT` type pun breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: I'm happy to break the rules as long as it works.

Comment: If it was me that signed up for this nasty task, I would just bite the bullet and do the job right. Every function that returns a struct by value should instead take a pointer to a struct as the first parameter, e.g. `void newObj(newobj, a, b, c) Obj *newobj;` Then the function call becomes, for example, `newObj(&a, 'a', '1', 1);` Note that you need to touch the function signature, the return statement, and every function call anyways (to insert your magical `OBJ2INT` and `INT2OBJ` macros). So the only additional work needed is to search/replace `newobj.` with `newobj->` in the function body.

Comment: You are right, but the code for awk is generated by lex and yacc scripts so I would have to do this everytime there is a compile or rewrite awk without the use of lex and yacc.!  Hence why I want to avoid it.

Comment: Did you try to use a `union` of `Obj` and `int32`? -- Does your old compiler (which one is it, BTW?) accept temporary variables in comma-separated expressions in parentheses like `Obj x = (int32 t = f(...), *(Obj*)&t);`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: The code does not break the strict aliasing rule because the compiler OP is using does not use the C standard.

Comment: The question cannot be answered definitively without information about the compiler being used. In standard C, the idiomatic ways to reinterpret the bytes of one object as another type are to use a union or to copy them as bytes (often via `memcpy`). While these nominally involve extra operations to store into one union member and load from another or to copy bytes, modern compilers generally recognize these operations and optimize them, so they may result in no generate code at all, just a use of the existing data as the new type…

Comment: … Since you are using an unnamed old compiler, we do not know what it will do, and we do not know how to craft a workaround that would do the desired job efficiently. If your compiler supports compound literals, you can try `#define ObjectToUint32(x) ((union { Obj o; uint32_t u; }) {x} .u)` and `#define Uint32ToObject(x) ((union { uint32_t u; Obj o; }) {x} .o)`. If those do not work, you could try solutions with `memcpy`, but they cannot be written in a standard C expression alone; you need statement expressions (a GCC extension to C) or non-expression code.

Comment: Microware K & R C compiler for Microware OS9

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Thank you. Those defines worked on my cross development system.  They didn't work on the K & R compiler.  They are clever though!

Comment: I managed this one #define FLNG2OBJ(x) ({int t ; t = x ; *(Obj*)& t;}) which works on gcc but not in K & R.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks. Nice one.  Tried that on K & R and not accepted.

Comment: suggest tagging the question for the compiler, since you are asking about specific compiler quirks, not any kind of standard C

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the whole point.  K & R C cannot assign or pass structures/unions.

So converting the int32 to a structure and assigning to another structure is never going to work. Can't assign structures!  So the structure must always be converted to an int32. because int32 can be assigned and passed. The solution was to change this :

```
b = INT2OBJ newObj('b', '2', 2); /* this is not allowed. even though the value is on the stack there is no address for return value */
```

to this :

```
   OBJ2INT b = newObj('b', '2', 2);
```

INT2OBJ is never required.  What was required was moving the INT2OBJ from the right to a OBJ2INT on the left of the assignment!